Handling UTXOs in Partially Signed Bitcoin Transactions (PSBTs) and Potential Double-Spend Scenario
I'm working with Partially Signed Bitcoin Transactions (PSBTs) and have a question about the behavior of transactions when the same UTXOs are involved in multiple transactions. Suppose I have a transaction created as a PSBT that requires multiple signatures. I sign it first, and before the second signer completes their part, I attempt to spend the same UTXOs in a different transaction.
PSBT Completion: What happens if I broadcast a new transaction using the same UTXOs before the PSBT is fully signed and broadcast? Can the new transaction be confirmed before the PSBT, making the PSBT invalid?
Double-Spend Protection: How does the Bitcoin network handle this scenario? Is the first transaction that gets confirmed the only one recognized, thus invalidating the other?
Wallet Behavior: What role do wallets play in managing UTXOs to prevent potential double-spends in such scenarios? Do they typically prevent the creation of a second transaction that would use the same UTXOs already allocated in a partially signed PSBT?
Any insights on how the Bitcoin protocol and network handle these situations would be very helpful.

Your question is about what happens when a transaction gets broadcast which tries to spend outputs that are already spent. It is unrelated to PSBT; PSBT is just one technology that helps wallets cooperate in constructing a transaction together, but how that transaction comes to be here is irrelevant here.
The answer is that Bitcoin nodes will not let you spend outputs which are already spent in a confirmed block. The transaction will be ignored.
If a transaction has already been broadcast, but not confirmed, which spends the same outputs, nodes may or may not accept the transaction, based on whether the new transaction pays a higher feerate, whether the old one opted into the BIP125 (signalling replaceability), and on the local policies of the node involved. There is no guarantee that all nodes behave the same way.

how blockchain knows that certain utxo is locked for psbt as it isnt on chain data ?

@NersesAsaturyan It does not. It's a feature of the wallet.
